# How to View Script log from Graphical Interface?

Tags: sql-server, user-interface, editor, sql-server-2012

I've created a database in MS SQL Server 2012 and now I am creating simple tables.

I know you can create a table through the graphical form format with drop-down boxes or through actual script.

My question is: does SQL Server 2012 have a script generator that is being built as you create tables in the graphical format? Like how in Dreamweaver if you use the WYSIWYG interface, it is generating script in HTML in the editor.

I feel it would be easier for me to learn step by step what is going on in script as I create tables in the manual drop-down boxes.

Comment: This Q&A may be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365228/sql-server-2012

Comment: Most of the interfaces in Management Studio have a script icon in the toolbar where you can view and run the script rather than having SSMS apply your changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see a script icon that when you hover over it, it will show "Generate Script" or "Script Table As" after you make a table or change a table.  If you click those, you will see what you've done in the graphical form, but in script form.  This should help you see how to generate T-SQL code for doing the same thing in the graphical form.