# TSQL | Create Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two databases on my local. I wish to use tsql to script out one of the two databases in its *entirety* (schema only) and save it in one .sql script. Is this possible for SQL 2012? And if so, how may I go about doing it? I am using GUI to do this right now but want to use tsql query if possible. I can't use any 3rd party tools.

Thank you

*UPDATE*: I am using the RIGHT CLICK > GENERATE script method right now. I want to avoid that and find a way to generate the database generation tsql script by some way other than using SSMS GUI. Also, I want to script the entire database and not just tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create SQL script that create database and tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771047/create-sql-script-that-create-database-and-tables)

Comment: Do you wish to generate a SQL script of your DB, or do you wish to have a _SQL script that generates a SQL script_ of your DB?

Comment: Why do you want to do this with SQL ? You could make C#/Vb.net code to do this.

Comment: AdmiralAdama: Thx/sry will chk it out.

TimLehner: I want a SQL script that generate SQL script of my DB so I can call that script to create DB.

Boray: Can you point me to a tutorial or something that does this in C#?

Comment: SSMS has a tool to do that see [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365228/sql-server-2012) for how to use it

Comment: "I want a SQL script that generate SQL script of my DB so I can call that script to create DB." I don't think a complete SQL script exists for this purpose, and it would be different for each version of SQL Server. There are many tools that already do this and are already complete, tested, and debugged. You could potentially fire up profiler and attempt to capture the SQL commands sent to SQL Server while a tool runs, if you actually found one to exclusively work that way.

Comment: Serpiton: thx for the suggestion. I am currently using the GUI method as shown in that thread. I am trying to avoid using it and create the script on demand w/o any gui interaction. Timlehner: That profiler probing idea is really interesting. Do you know of any FREE 3rd party tool that meets my requirements and would play well with sql profiler?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following 2 ways.

1. Use Powershell.
2. Use the SMO classes, the `Scripter` class in particular. The GUI Tools are wrappers around this class.

#### Here's the solution for #1.

[Using Powershell to Generate Table-Creation Scripts](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/using-powershell-to-generate-table-creation-scripts/). By [Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/author/robert-sheldon/) on **simple-talk.com**

#### Here's a solution for #2.

See this [MSDN Example scripting all tables in a database with SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162153.aspx).

Relevant code below. Change the database name and other details as appropriate.

```
//Connect to the local, default instance of SQL Server. 
{ 
   Server srv = default(Server); 
   srv = new Server(); 
   //Reference the AdventureWorks database. 
   Database db = default(Database); 
   db = srv.Databases("AdventureWorks"); 
   //Define a Scripter object and set the required scripting options. 
   Scripter scrp = default(Scripter); 
   scrp = new Scripter(srv); 
   scrp.Options.ScriptDrops = false; 
   scrp.Options.WithDependencies = true; 
   //Iterate through the tables in database and script each one. Display the script. 
   //Note that the StringCollection type needs the System.Collections.Specialized namespace to be included. 
   Table tb = default(Table); 
   Urn[] smoObjects = new Urn[2]; 
   foreach ( tb in db.Tables) { 
      smoObjects = new Urn[1]; 
      smoObjects(0) = tb.Urn; 
      if (tb.IsSystemObject == false) { 
         StringCollection sc = default(StringCollection); 
         sc = scrp.Script(smoObjects); 
         string st = null; 
         foreach ( st in sc) { 
            Console.WriteLine(st); 
         } 
      } 
   } 
}
```

If you want to script out ALL the DB objects, and not just tables, take a look at [the powershell script in this page](http://patlau.blogspot.com/2012/09/generate-sqlserver-scripts-with.html) where it says "Full Script". It takes care of table and relationship dependencies also.

Comment: this might be what I need. I am like a total newb in PS so I will go with c#. Is it possible to script not just tables but all Objs into one single .sql script?

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer. The link has the full script to do what you need. PS is quite easy actually. There isn't much of a learning curve since the commands are sub-set of .Net commands and class Libraries.

Comment: I get the following msg: 

EXCEPTION: Invalid path: There is no collection of UnresolvedEntity objects that is a child of Database.
Exception calling "GetSmoObject" with "1" argument(s): "Attempt to retrieve data for object failed for Server 'fdsfsd'. "
At line:36 char:5
+     $item = $srv.GetSmoObject($urn)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException

It created many TAB, couple UDF scripts and such. How do i script everything in one DB (if possible)?